# Getting "ECONNREFUSED" error after booting my computer. I'm using an express server and I'm trying to see that i can make requests

Tags: node.js, express, docker, error-handling

I'm working on a project and I have seeded some data. But when I try to do any request to my localhost I get this error:

```js
// 20170624132844
// http://localhost:4310/campuses

{
  "code": "ECONNREFUSED",
  "errno": "ECONNREFUSED",
  "syscall": "connect",
  "address": "127.0.0.1",
  "port": 5432
}
```

my requests were working prior to me restarting my computer, not sure what is happening here. Can someone please explain what the error means and how to handle it.
I'm including my app.js code here in case it would help.

```js
'use strict';
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'){
  require('dotenv').config();
}

//use npm install cors - this stands for Cross- origin resouce sharing
const express = require('express');
const app = express(), bunyanLogger = require('express-bunyan-logger');
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const Bunyan = require('bunyan');
const compress = require('compression');

const cohortsRoute = require('./routes/cohorts');
const campusesRoute = require('./routes/campuses');
const usersRoute = require('./routes/users');
const skills = require('./routes/skills');

const morgan = require('morgan');

switch (app.get('env')) {
  case 'development':
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    break;

  case 'production':
    app.use(morgan('short'));
    break;

  default:
}


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join('public')));
// app.use('/api/authenticate', authenticateController.authenticate)//from video tutorial.


//other modules that might need to be required later

// const users = require('./routes/users');
// const admin = require('./routes/admin');
// const cohorts = require('./routes/cohorts');// already up there.
// const campus = require('./routes/campus');
// const projects = require('./routes/projects')
// const skills = require('./routes/skills');
// const profile = require('./routes/profile');

// app.use(users)
app.use(campusesRoute);
app.use(cohortsRoute);
app.use(usersRoute);
// app.use(campus)
// app.use(projects)
app.use(skills)

app.use((req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(404);
});


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World, Ivonne at work here');
  res.send(path.resolve(__dirname, 'buil'))
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  if(app.get('env') !== 'test'){
    console.log(`Galvanize Connect server listening on port ${PORT}`);
  }
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: The two ports you mentioned do not match (4310 and 5432).

Comment: I was running port 4310 in the back and that was working. Except when make de call form localhost

Comment: @mscdex my localhost port is 4310 so I'm not sure where 5432 is coming from.